# NSBundle.mainBundle() returns nil

Tags: ios, nsbundle, mainbundle

I just reinstalled my mac and Xcode. Then `[NSBundle mainBundle]` always returns nil for some reason I don't know.

Thank you very much!

Here is the screenshot of my debug pane:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have built your code in release mode. In release mode the debugger is unreliable. Variables can be optimized away. Switch to debug mode and try again.

Comment: So nice a day meeting you:)

Comment: @DuncanC out of curiosity, how did you know it's in release mode from that screenshot?

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai, if you look in the lower right of the window it says "xxx was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available." That last part is the most important point.